Solve $x^2+6x-15120=0$

Solve $x^2+6x-15120=0$

So I could just use the quadratic equation and get the answer. However, I have factored $15120 = 2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$.
I know I need two factors with a difference between them of $6$ due to the $6x$ term. Is there a way to deduce those two factors from $ 2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$?
Thanks.

Trial and error.  And an acknowledgement that you have absolutely no reason to assume there is an integer answer.  What about completing the square as a "compromise? $x^2 + 6x-15120=0\implies x^2 + 6x + 9 = 15129$ and now we just have to factor $15129$ to see if it is a perfect square.  That way you are still being "hands on" and not relying on a magic formula without comprehension. ... Um... why are you reluctant to use the quadratic formula?

The numbers in the radical get too big. So it's easier to find factors first.

Okay... so a trip to the calcutor shows it can be done.  THe difference must be even and a multiple of $3$ and at least one must be even and one a multiple of $3$ so both must be.  So $ab = 15120; a-b=6$ can be reduced by dividing both $a$ and $b$ by $6$ and gettin $cd=2^23\cdot 5\cdot 7; c-d =1$. $1$ is odd so we must distribute $4,3,5,7$ to get a difference of $1$.  Comparing sizes... well, trial and error makes $3\times 7 - 4\times 5 = 1$ .  So $15120=(6\times 21)(6\times 20)=126\times 120$.

"The numbers in the radical get too big. So it's easier to find factors first."  Avoid the multiplying by $4$ biz. $a=1$ and $b$ and $c$ are both even.  So $x = -\frac b2 \pm \sqrt{\frac {b^2}4 -c}$.  That's what completing the square would have given you.

Or... using the quadratic formula "blind"  $x =\frac {-6\pm \sqrt{36+4\times 1520}}2$.  As $4$ clearly factors out of the root $x = \frac {-6\pm 2\sqrt{9+1520}}2 = \pm \sqrt{1529}-3$.  Just have to find $\sqrt{1529}$ which isn't hard to do by hand.

Yes fleablood you gave me what I'm looking for. But I don't quite understand it. The difference must be even and a multiple of $3$. Because the difference is $6$. Understand. $ab=15120, a-b=6$ I understand. Then I get lost. Why divide both $a$ and $b$ by $6$? And what is $cd$?

$c = \frac a6$ and $d =\frac b6$.  You must distribute $2$ between $a$ and $b$ so they are both even or both odd.  That means $a$ and $b$ are both even.  You must distribut $3$ over $a$ and $b$ so that either they are both div by $3$ or ,.... not.  So they must both be divisible by $3$.  So both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $6$.

You noticed that the two roots are of the form: $-u,v$ such that
$$u-v=6\text{ and }uv=2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7.$$
You conjectured that $u,v$ are integers. At least one of them is then even (since their product is), and then both are (since their difference is). Similarly, both must be divisible by $3$. The two integers $$a:=u/6,\quad b:=v/6$$ are then determined by
$$a-b=1\text{ and }ab=3\cdot4\cdot5 \cdot 7.$$
The (unique and) obvious solution
$$a=3\cdot7=21,\quad b=4\cdot5=20$$
then confirms your conjecture.

Thanks for the answer. Can you explain why both must be divisible by $3$?

This is exactly the same reasoning as for $2$: replace everywhere "even" with "divisible by $3$".

I can see one factor must be divisible by $3$, because $15120$ itself is divisible by $3$. But how do you prove the other factor is also divisible by $3$?

Like for $2$: because the sum is. (Oops: their difference! I edited my answer.) If $p\mid u-v$ and $p\mid u$ or $v$, then $p\mid u$ and $v$.

I'm hesitant to answer the question you asked because 1) we have no reason to assume it can be factored and if it can't that's a waste of a lot of time and 2) you should use the quadratic formula.  This is exactly what it is for. Your comment "The numbers in the radical get too big. So it's easier to find factors first." is not valid because any factors $b^2$ and $4ac$ have in common will be factored out.
But to answer your question:  If you have $ab = M$ and $a+b=N$ and $M$ and $N$ have common divisor $d$ then $d|a$ and $d$ divides $b$.
Here you have $ab = 15120= 2^4\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5\cdot 7$ and $a-b = 6$.  We need to distribute the factors $2,2,2,2,3,3,3,5,7$ to $a$ and $b$ in such a way that $a-b=6$.
$a-b=6= 2\times 3$  If we give a $2$ to $a$ then we have to give a $2$ to $b$ or else $a-b$ would be odd.  (And same thing if we give a $2$ to $b$.)  So we have to give a $2$ to both $a$ and $b$.
And if we give a $3$ to $a$ then we have to give a $3$ to $b$ as well.  If $a$ is divisible by $3$ and $b$ is not, then $a-b$ will not be divisible by $3$.  So we have to give a $3$ to both of them.
So $a$ and $b$ are both divisible by $6$.  Let $a= 6c$ and $b =6d$ so $ab = 36cd = 2^4\cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 36\times 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and $a-b = 6c-6d=6$ so $c-d = 1$.
Okay, we need to distribute $2,2,3,5,7$ among $c,d$ to get $c-d=1$.  $1$ is odd so we can't have $c,d$ both even, so the $2^2$ must go to one or the other.
In other words we have to distribute $3,4,5,7$ to $c,d$ so that $c-d=1$. Simple trial and error is $c=3\cdot 7=21$ and $d= 4\cdot 5=20$.  And so $a = 6\cdot 21=126$ and $b=6\cdot 20=120$
And $x^2 + 6x + 15120= (x+126)(x-120)$
We can verify that as $(x+126)(x-120) =$
$(x + 6\times 3\cdot 7)(x-6\times 4\cdot 5) =$
$x^2 + (6\times 21- 6\times 20)x - 6^2\times 3\cdot 7\cdot 4\cdot 5=$
$x^2 +6(21-20)x - 2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7=$
$x + 6x - 15120$.

By the Rational Root Theorem, any rational roots must be factors of 15120, i.e., in the set $\pm \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 27, 28, 30, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 54, 56, 60, 63, 70, 72, 80, 84, 90, 105, 108, 112, 120, 126, 135, 140, 144, 168, 180, 189, 210, 216, 240, 252, 270, 280, 315, 336, 360, 378, 420, 432, 504, 540, 560, 630, 720, 756, 840, 945, 1008, 1080, 1260, 1512, 1680, 1890, 2160, 2520, 3024, 3780, 5040, 7560, 15120 \}$
Since you know that the factors must be close in absolute value (but opposite signs) to each other (a difference of $6$), you can start your search around $\pm\sqrt{15120} \approx \pm 122.963409$.
It turns out that $-126$ and $120$ satisfy the original equation.
Of course, this approach only works if the roots are rational.  If they're irrational or complex, the Rational Root Theorem isn't much help.
